# Black screen after apt-get dist-upgrade on kali

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I've a problem in my Kali Linux after the last Distro upgrade which I did from terminal using the below command

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After the upgrade I did the 'Purge' and 'Auto Remove' using apt command and rebooted my Kali. Now my computer ends with black screen after the grub selection. I don't know where to start or where to end.

I made almost ~5hrs googling and surfed internet all round, But no luck. I hope someone here can help me.

I'm ready to provide info about the OS info because I'm able to access my Kali using recovery mode(fail safe).

I would really appreciate for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, that's an old risk with upgrades, instead of doing a clean install when a new release comes out. Standard practice is to have a backup of your data, so just do a clean re-install and then copy your data back (home, etc) and boom done

Comment: much appreciate your time answering my question. But I didn't knew that this could cause problems like this. I wish I could do a clean installation but I literally hate doing that because a person who doesn't have any source of backup drive. Any other suggestions @Xen2050 or would you give me some tips on how often I have to update my Kali.

Comment: I'm not sure, just guessing but you can still get into recovery mode, so purging & reinstalling packages (perhaps rolling back to an older version) is an option, maybe it's a display/window manager that's having problems. Should still be able to back up your home files so that's good... it's possible a config file in your home is causing problems too, try creating a new user & logging in as them?

Comment: that's a good Idea 'creating a new user'. I haven't try that before. I will add a user from recovery mode and let you know the results.

Comment: As you mentioned @Xen2050 I've searched a lot and even I've took more than 5hrs (not as a stretch) to solve this problem because this is annoying me like anything and came to a conclusion that this could be a display driver problem. I did downloaded the Intel Graphics driver for amd64 but don't know how to install from recovery mode using terminal. Do you have any suggestion for me

Comment: its been a long time and I hope you are well @Xen2050 I tried with new user account but it does the same. Now I'm going to override the installation part. I really hope that I wont mess-up my disk.

Comment: If purging/reinstalling some packages didn't work (and I'm not sure which ones to even try) then a re-install is always an option. A small USB flash drive could even hold backups of your home, and maybe even be the live boot device too

Comment: I performed a re-installation it worked fine. Thank you @Xen2050

Answer (score 0):

When you load your Kali, do you have the option of choosing a previous version to boot from? I did that also after endless hours of searching (for what I think was from a similar problem), and it was the only thing I was able to get to work.

I am not sure if this is the same problem/issue, but this may (I hope) help (or it may not).

Just some background, again, not sure if it's the same issue, but about 2 weeks ago, I upgraded, and the next time I loaded my computer up, I was also met with a black screen, some errors, I thought it was because of my encrypted disk, and that I possibly accidentally renamed my boot disk.  Spent hours trying to resolve it to no avail (didn't help that I didn't know the accurate name of my encrypted boot disk).  I was desperate to just get back onto my home screen(lol), so I ended up from my boot screen, loading from the previous version of Kali (I'm not sure if you also have this option).  After I did this, I just did an apt-get update, I think I configured some settings with my disk (again, my error may have not been b/c of the upgrade, but the timing was weird), and I've been able to boot up my kali normally ever since.

I am right now as I'm typing this, doing the dist-upgrade and upgrade, and after reading this post, thinking I should've definitely done a backup first, lol.

Comment: its true @woke zombie to have a backup before upgrade the Kali or any linux distro. I thought to do so, but finally ended up in a loop of black screen. To be honest I hate black screen (blue too) because I came from windows platform and starting loving Linux because it has lot of options to user(power users too). Finally, I've reinstalled Kali. Now it is working fine(no more hard face). The most funny part is re-install doesn't take much of my time(only 10minutes) so I prefer people to re-install, so that they can learn.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a similar problem where this happened after I did a `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. For me to solve the problem I had to do the following:

**MAKE SURE THERE IS A WIRED INTERNET CONNECTION TO YOUR COMPUTER**

Then, boot the computer into recovery mode. This will give you a terminal. Once that is done, you can do:

```
`apt-get update`
`apt-get upgrade`
`apt-get dist-upgrade`
```

This fixed my problem. Hope it helps someone else.